# Is “The Tigris is the river we are investigating” grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, passive-voice, syntax, formal-language

I saw the following sentence in formal writing:

> The Tigris is the river we are investigating.

(Please don't change the sentence to "We are investigating the Tigris river" or etc..)

**Questions:**

1. Why can we put "**we are investigating**" in the end of the sentence, and according to the Sentence Analysis which part it (we are investigating) is?
2. Why not "The Tigris is the river we investigate"?

Comment: Please cite your source. What is the name of the book (if it is one) and/or add a link to where you saw it. It would also be helpful to know if the name of a different river was mentioned previously.

Comment: No.2 would suggest the people *investigating* (marine biologists? researchers?) regularly inspect that specific river.

Comment: _More_ formally, "we are investigating" could be preceded by _that_ or _which_. It is a clause explaining the significance of the Tigris.

Comment: #2 implies to me that the Tigris is the only river that is investigated by the people in the group "we".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"... we investigated" / "... we are investigating" is a [relative clause](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-clauses-defining-and-non-defining) where the relative pronoun "that" [has been omitted](https://open.books4languages.com/english-b1-grammar/chapter/omission-of-relative-pronouns/).

You could also say:

> The Tigris is the river **that** we are investigating.

or

> The Tigris is the river **which** we are investigating.

which might help you to understand the type of clause.

---

For question 2, it's a different tense:

"we investigate" is [present indefinite tense](https://www.learngrammar.net/a/examples-of-present-indefinite-tense), which usually means this is a thing that happens regularly or normally. Since you used the definite article "the", it implies there is only one *only* river that you regularly or normally investigate. You never investigate other rivers.

"we are investigating" is [present progressive tense](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/present_progressive_tense.htm) which means this is a thing that is happening right now, at the current time. Since you used the definite article "the", it implies there is only one river that you are investigating *right now*. You are not investigating other rivers *right now*, but perhaps you do regularly investigate other rivers.

---

It is possible that you only regularly investigate the Tigris, but you are currently investigating another river for some special reason. In this case, you should draw attention to it:

> The Tigris is the river we *usually* investigate, *but* the Euphrates is the river we are investigating *today*, because the other team found some interesting data there.

instead of just saying:

> The Tigris is the river we investigate. The Euphrates is the river we are investigating.

because that is strange.

---

As you have pointed out, we would normally say "We investigate the Tigris" but the way you have said it is also valid.